# Do I need to replace my rims to move up to a larger width tire?

Tags: tire

I have a 1965 Schwinn Speedster that has 26 x 1-3/8 rims and tires.i have more than enough room to run larger width tires, I'm just not sure if I need to replace rims?

Comment: What size tires are you planning to move up to?

Comment: http://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html  Has rim width versus tire width section.

Comment: It's not worth the effort/expense to upgrade a bike with fractional 26" tires to decimal tires.  Only justified if the bike is a museum piece, and then you'd want to keep everything to factory spec.

Answer (score 4):

You're in a bit a predicament because of the age of your bicycle. If I remember correctly, your rims are `S6` (Schwinn's designation), and therefore are `ISO-597mm`. This size was used by Schwinn are their mid-range to high-end bicycles in the 60s and 70s, and on a few British bikes. It is not compatible with nearly every modern tire. However, Kenda does make a `1-3/8"` tire in that size. It's not bigger, but it could be a viable replacement when they inevitably need to be.

If you want a better selection of tires to choose from, I'd recommend taking it to your local bike shop. They'll be able to assess how you'd like to proceed. You'd likely be replacing your rims, and possibly the whole wheels. The prices could range widely and will depend on your area, so I don't want to comment on that.

Comment: Yeah, it's important to not confuse 26 x 1-3/8 with 26 x 1.375. They are completely different sizes. [According to Sheldon](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html) there was even an old 26 x 1.375 that would be incompatible with a modern 26 x 1.375.

Answer (score 4):

As usual Sheldon Brown has an answer
[tire sizing](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html)
Look for the section on rim and tire width

On an older bike if you need new rims you might as well go with the whole wheel.